# Undefined property: mysqli_stmt::$bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, call-user-func-array

I want to bind variable number parameters using `call_user_func_array` in this way(please read comments at the code):

```php
function dbQuery() 
{
    global $dbconnection;
    if (func_num_args() < 1 || func_num_args() === 2) {
       return error('خطای داخلی');
    } else if (func_num_args() === 1) {
       $stmt = $dbconnection->prepare(func_get_arg(0)); // Creating stmt
       if (!$stmt) {
           return error('خطای پایگاه داده');
       }
       if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        return error('خطا در تعامل با پایگاه داده');
       }
       return $stmt;
    } else {
       $args = func_get_args();
       $stmt = $dbconnection->prepare($args[0]); // args[0] is the query with question marks
       if (!$stmt) {
        return error('خطای پایگاه داده');
        }
       array_shift($args);
       foreach ($args as $index => $arg) {
          ${'arg' . $index} = $dbconnection->real_escape_string($arg); // making args as variables because bind_params does not allow direct values
          $args[$index] = ${'arg' . $index};
       }
       if (!call_user_func_array($stmt->bind_param,$args)) { // ERROR IS HERE LINE 67
          return error('خطای امنیتی پایگاه داده');
       }
       if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        return error('خطا در تعامل با پایگاه داده');
       }
       return $stmt;
    }
 }
 $stmt = dbQuery('SELECT * FROM payments WHERE id=?','i',31);
 $result = dbCheck($stmt);
 var_dump($result->fetch_all());
```

and the error is:

```
PHP Warning:  Undefined property: mysqli_stmt::$bind_param in /home/mwxgaf/w/projects/foodorder/test.php on line 67
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($function) must be a valid callback, no array or string given in /home/mwxgaf/w/projects/foodorder/test.php:67
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mwxgaf/w/projects/foodorder/test.php(76): dbQuery()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/mwxgaf/w/projects/foodorder/test.php on line 67
```

Comment: Can you just use the splat operator? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682298/231316

Comment: Why are you manually escaping the arguments when using prepared statements? Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem? I would assume that `$stmt->bind_param` is not defined in any way

Comment: @ChrisHaas I used your solution & it solved another error too ; thanks

Comment: `elseif` should be one word in PHP. We shouldn't see any real_escaping with a prepatred statement.  Variable variables seem fun when you first learn about them, but eventually you will realize that they prevent you from using powerful array functions on data that is sensibly contained in an array.  When you think your code needs varuable variables or `eval()`, you probably need to refactor your code.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/13570957/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/20886289/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/1913899/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/45926489/2943403

Comment: How about `function dbQuery(string $sql, ...$theRest)`? This way, if `$theRest` is an empty array, you know that you don't need a prepared statement at all.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323556/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call_user_func_array` expects a callable as the first argument, and `$stmt->bind_param` is the wrong format for this. `[$stmt, 'bind_param']` would be the proper callable

---

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1. Accessing protected and private methods from within a class is allowed.